# kml file half loaded on google maps

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am loading kml files on Google maps. 99% of the time it works but there have been instance when the kml file does not fully load. Currently i am caching the kml files every night in memcache so it does not need to send request to Google every time. I have attached pictures where you can see the kml file is half loaded. I cannot see any errors in Apache, browser or application logs. Can anyone help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT0zQ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJPc.jpg

Comment: How large are the kml file? It's possible something is timing out somewhere sometimes.

Comment: the are 68kb, i don't believe they are timing out. half the kml is loaded, and a square block is missing, how ever if i put my mouse over the square block that is missing i can still click on the lines that originated from the kml but you cannot see this square block. the kml request is sent on idle event, i need it to trigger every time the user moves the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are rendered server side by GMaps, as image tiles.

Unfortunatly sometimes Gmaps - for some unknown reason fails to draw some tiles. And once its failed, the failed tile is cached. You can sometimes get round it by refreshing the browser.

I dont think there is a known solution, other than forcing GMaps to try to redraw the tiles - easiest way to do that is to change the url of the kml file - so gmaps renders it from scratch.

Could just add a fake paramater in JS, which is then ignored by your server, but gmaps sees it as a new url.

Comment: Right now i am redrawing the kml from cache on every zoom and movement. if there is any other better work around please post up. http://www.spectrumasa.com/mcmap/